# PHP strstr( , ,true) not working on cron job

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP-file (pc.php) which runs the `strstr( , ,true)` on a few lines. I know this function is only supported in PHP version 5.3.0 or higher. I have a webhost at fhero.net, with PHP version 5.3. When I manually run the script via my browser, it runs without errors/warnings. But if I want to run it periodically in a cron job I do get errors.

This is the command: `php -f /home/<username>/public_html/pc.php`
(I'm not allowed to change the `php -f /home/<username>/` part)

The pc.php gives faulty results and this is the cron output:

> Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr() in /home//public_html/pc.php on line 11

Where does this warning come from and how can I fix it?

Comment: need to see the full code

Comment: Is it really `strstr( , ,true)`?

Comment: `strstr` supported both php4 and php5. Third parameter allowed in php5.3. So it means that your version of php is not 5.3

Comment: cli php may not be the same version, check on the command line with `php -i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the server running your cron uses another PHP version lower than 503000. Try so get that version first:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('/home/username/some/path/phpversion.txt', php_version());
```

Run this script as a cron. If that version is below 5.3, you can't use strstr. Maybe you can define it yourself:

```
// before 5.3.0
if(!function_exists('strstr')) {
    // define this function yourself here
}
```

You should also be able to test your CLI version using `php -v` in your command line.

Comment: It seems that the php version is different for cron jobs. Thanks for the response.